# Inner query in like statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT data FROM MSG_1 WHERE created>'2014-02-24' and data like '%2012177%'
```

here rather than hard coding dataId value `'2012177'`, i need to get this value from query like:

```
SELECT distinct dataId FROM Item where Src='MKT' and ValueDt>'2014-02-01'.
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

you could probably try :

```
SELECT data FROM MSG_1 WHERE created>'2014-02-24' and data in 
(SELECT distinct dataId FROM Item where Src='MKT' and ValueDt>'2014-02-01')
```

Comment: here data is not exactly same as dataid its just contains this string something like data = 'hereIsThe2012177Example'

Comment: in that case you might have to split the string you obtain in the second query since it might return more than one record and the like might not work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.data 
FROM MSG_1 m
JOIN (SELECT distinct dataId as d 
      FROM Item 
      where Src='MKT' and ValueDt>'2014-02-01'
     ) t
ON m.data like '%'+t.d+'%'
WHERE m.created>'2014-02-24'
```

edited to suit sql server.

Comment: The `||` syntax is for Oracle. For SqlServer use a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

SELECT 

      data 

FROM 

    MSG_1 M1

JOIN (SELECT distinct dataId FROM Item where Src='MKT' and ValueDt>'2014-02-01') M2 

    ON M1.Data = concat('%', M2.dataId ,'%')

WHERE 
     
      M1.created>'2014-02-24'